# Looking for Inkscape but does not seem to be a page

Tags: discussion

Looking for help and give advice for Inkscape but apparently that room does not exist. Can this topic be addressed here? If not, please advise.

Comment: If you're looking for a chat room, indeed, they go away if too much time passes, but you can post in The Ink Spot initially. If enough people are up for it, new chat rooms can be made.

Answer (score 6):

Hello and welcome to GDSE!

Inkscape is on topic here. 
You can view a list of [current inkscape contributions here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inkscape).